# String to create a full database in SQLite

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

I wrote this string to create a Database in SQLite, but I get an error **CREATE unexpected** right before "CREATE corso". This is the string:

```
static final String DATABASE_CREAZIONE =
        "CREATE TABLE utente (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "nome text not null, cognome text not null, "
                + "email text not null, password text not null);"
                + "CREATE TABLE corso (id integer primary key autoincrement," +
                "nome text not null);" +
                "CREATE TABLE prenotazione (id_utente integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "id_docente integer primary key autoincrement, data DATETIME not null);"+
                "CREATE TABLE docenza (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "nome_corso text not null, nome_prof text not null); "+
                "CREATE TABLE professore (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "nome text not null, cognome text not null); ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only the Android Studio IDE giving the warning but for a valid reason.

Android `SQLiteDatabase` `execSQL()` you typically use for executing SQL like this only executes a single statement at a time. Anything after `;` will be ignored.

You need to split the SQL to separate `execSQL()` calls. That would also get rid of the IDE warning and execute the other parts of the SQL so you can detect runtime issues like reported by Boken in his answer.